# Ruby on Rails controller syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails, and just working my way through my first solo project, but I seem to be running into a syntax error with a constant not being initialized (Ive gotten several of these, but each seems to have a different cause.....not quite sure how i keep getting the same error with different causes :)):

```
uninitialized constant DatastringsController::Datastrings
```

DatastringsController:

```
class DatastringsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    @datastrings = Datastrings.new(datastrings_params) #ERROR returned on this line
    @datastrings.save
    redirect_to @datastrings
  end

  def show
    @datastrings = Datastrings.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def datastrings_params
    params.require(:datastrings).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

I believe my form is correct:

```
<%= form_for :datastrings, url: datastrings_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `Model class names` supposed to be singular.Change `Datastrings` to `Datastring`.And also don't forget to change the `model file name` as well.

Comment: Suggesting you to follow a tutorial or some kind.  One of the ones I've heard frequently is http://www.railstutorial.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you have is here:

```
<%= form_for :datastrings, url: datastrings_path do |f| %>
```

[**form_for**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) really should be populated with an ActiveRecord object, as this allows Rails to build the relative paths it requires correctly.

Although I don't know *why* this is the case, your current setup is basically trying to render `DatastringsController::Datastrings` -- primarily because you've not set up your `form_for` correctly

--

**Fix**

If you want to create a `datastring` object, I'd follow convention and do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :datastrings

#app/controllers/datastrings_controller.rb
Class DatastringsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @datastring = Datastring.new
   end

   def create
      @datastring = Datastring.new(datastring_params)
      @datastring.save
   end

   private

   def datastring_params
      params.require(:datastring).permit(:title, :text)
   end
end

#app/views/datastrings/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @datastring do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

**YOU ALSO NEED TO NAME YOUR MODELS IN SINGULAR**

Looking at it now, it seems that your main issue is likely that you've named your model as a `plural`.

The reason this will be bad is that when you load Rails, it will load all your models, and consequently, allow you to call them by referencing their class name. If a model is plural, I don't think it will load it correctly, causing the error you've highlighted

If you name your model to the following, it should be better:

```
#app/models/datastring.rb
Class Datastring < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That solved my problem, but as far as im aware (and im probably wrong) I havent generated a model yet, just a controller datastrings that I am trying to store form data in.